General differential equation for Energy transfer
In my textbook of Fundamentals of Momentum, Heat, and Mass Transfer by Welty, it is said that $$\nabla \cdot k\nabla T + \dot q + \Lambda = \rho \frac{Du}{Dt}+\rho\frac{D(gy)}{Dt}+\mathrm v \cdot \rho g + \mathrm v \cdot \mu \nabla^2 \mathrm v $$
and then it turns into
$$\nabla \cdot k\nabla T + \dot q + \Lambda = \rho C_v\frac{DT}{Dt}+ \mathrm v \cdot \mu \nabla^2 \mathrm v $$
It is said to only consider the potential in z direction. But I'm not sure how the gravitational term was erased. First confusion is about what $gy$ actually means. It seems that $y$ should be considered as displacement not direction to me. Second confusion is with all the substantial derivative and gravitational vector terms erased, with only z term left, how come $\rho g v_z \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} + v_z \rho g$ becomes zero? If potential of z direction is considered, doesn't displacment increase with the increase of z?

having the same question,i just found this
this may help you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3kVizLp-4c

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
